# Function Integration

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Please help me in integrating this function its been many hours and I don't know how to proceed nothing is helping substitution or series expansion.

This Function:

$$\frac{1}{x+2\tan(x)}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This integral has no elementary answers. Are you sure there are no bounds?

Comment: @NinadMunshi yes Im sure

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, no hope for a closed form.

What you can do is a series expansion. Using the one for $\tan(x)$ and then long division, you could get something like
$$\frac{1}{x+2 \tan (x)}=\frac{1}{3 x}-\frac{2 x}{27}-\frac{16 x^3}{1215}-\frac{38 x^5}{15309}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ Integrate termwise to get ... something.